Conditional Composition in SysML
Is there a good way of showing a conditional composition in SysML?  For example, a wheel could be composed of either a rim and a tubeless tire OR of a rim, a tube, and a tire.
I could use 0 to 1 multiplicity, but that would not really show an either or relationship between these options.

So, there are two types of wheels. Why not model them? You could have a generic abstract Wheel and two concrete wheels specializing it: One Tubeless Wheel and one Tubed Wheel.
In a specific car type you would then use one of the special wheels or the abstract wheel, if you want to leave it open. If you then further develop your design by specializing the abstract design, you can use bound references to fix the wheels to a concrete subtype of Wheel.
Of course you can also use constraints to specify the allowed combinations textually. However, I would prefer a graphical notation wherever possible.
